# Upgrading to EF Core 3 Broke All LINQ Queries

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I've read why (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) after I got the errors and I understand the explanation, but I'm not sure what needs to be changed.

So this won't work:

```
var result = (from ts in _context.TradesSeries
                          join tts in _context.TradesTrades
                          on ts.Id equals tts.SeriesId
                          where seriesIds.Contains(tts.SeriesId) && tts.FirstPartyId == null &&
                                tts.Status != "closed" && tts.Status != "cancelled"
                          group new { ts, tts } by new { tts.SeriesId } into g
                          select new TotalByIsin
                          {
                              SeriesId = g.Key.SeriesId,
                              IsinShortCode = g.Select(i => i.ts.Number).Distinct().First(),
                              Isin = g.Select(i => i.ts.Isin).Distinct().First(),
                              Amount = (double)g.Sum(pt => pt.tts.Amount),
                              NumberOfTrades = g.Count()
                          }).ToList();
            return result;
```

And neither will this:

```
var result = (from tt in _context.TradesTrades
                          join ts in _context.TradesSeries on tt.SeriesId equals ts.Id
                          join ttd in _context.TradesTradeDistributors on tt.Id equals ttd.TradeId
                          join to in _context.TradesOrganisations on ttd.DistributorId equals to.Id
                          where seriesIds.Contains(tt.SeriesId) && tt.FirstPartyId == null &&
                                      tt.Status != "closed" && tt.Status != "cancelled" && 
                                      to.DefaultDistributor !=1 && to.ExcludeDistSponView !=1 && to.ExcludeFromDwdpTotal !=1
                          join tc in _context.TradesCountries on to.CountryId equals tc.Id into tcj
                          from tc in tcj.DefaultIfEmpty() // GroupJoin -> left join
                          group new { tt, ts, ttd, to, tc } by new { ttd.DistributorId}
                          into tradeg
                          let commissionTotal = tradeg.Sum(trade => trade.ttd.Commission)
                          orderby commissionTotal descending
                          select new TopDistributors
                          {
                              //SeriesId = tradeg.Key.SeriesId,
                              DistributorName = tradeg.First().to.Name,
                              IsinShortCode = tradeg.First().ts.Number,
                              CountryName = tradeg.First().tc == null ? "N/A" : tradeg.First().tc.Name,
                              Amount = Math.Ceiling((double) commissionTotal)
                          }).Take(5).ToList();
             return result;
```

...and neither will any of the other 30 some odd queries I've constructed based on help from StackOverflow LINQ experts. What's considered to be client in these queries and what's not? Is there a simple fix to remedy this or should I just use Dapper and go straight SQL just in case Microsoft decides to break LINQ functionality again? Although, I'd rather not have to fully rewrite 30 queries before the rest of the team gets in tomorrow morning. ‍♂️

Thanks!

Comment: Note that this is because of the update to EF Core, not .NET Core. IIRC you can use EF6 on .NET Core as well.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I was able to rollback Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql to version 2.2.6 and everything is working again. 

Would still like to know how to fix these queries to upgrade when the time comes.

Comment: And I'd add that we develop on and deploy to non-Windows systems. I don't think EF6 is an option.

Comment: Based on the [release notes for EF 6.3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef-core-3-0-and-ef-6-3-general-availability/#what-s-new-in-ef-6-3), because EF6 works on .NET Core, it's also cross-platform

Comment: Which EF6 provider are you using? That might be a bigger issue -- the provider also has to support .NET Core.

Comment: What you've essentially done is ask us to fix your queries for you. Have you instead considered actually reading the page you linked and applying its suggestions? The section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#explicit-client-evaluation explicitly calls out using `string.Contains`, which is **exactly** what both of your queries are doing.

Comment: That's not correct, Ian. I didn't ask anyone to fix queries. I asked: "What's considered to be client in these queries and what's not?"

Comment: @ZevSpitz I'm not using EF6. I'm using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.

Comment: Oh! I apologize -- I assumed you were moving from EF6 to EF Core, not from an earlier version of EF Core to 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to rollback Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql to version 2.2.6 and everything is working again.

Will investigate what's client and what's not since Ian provided a link with one example that included a function call - which really doesn't answer the question I posted. I still don't know what's client and what's not...for example, is LET a client side thing?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the breaking changes preventing automatic client side evaluation.

You can use AsEnumerable() on your join then use the groupBy and select which are not translatable to SQL.